# Losing views with multiple fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I've been working on an app to display media that has a layout that resembles the below mockup. Each fragment is a pair of linearlayout elements with 4 custom layouts to show a imageview and textview.

If I have more than 2 fragments and flick right-left to navigate through the various fragments the 4 custom imageviews are not being displayed inside the fragment. I assume it's due to garbage collection resulting from Android loading all images onto the heap.

I've tried using the onResume() methods of each fragment to rebuild the layouts when they are visible, with disastrous results.

Since different users may have different fragment counts based on how they set up their media, what would be considered best practice for an activity that's image heavy like this. Also does anyone have any suggestions for how to tell if the fragment's layout needs to be rebuilt.

This is my first Android app, the learning curve feels quite steep.

[image: mockup]

EDIT: As requested, here is the adapter and the fragment.

```
public static class HomeScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public HomeScreenPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {            

        MediaPayload mediaWrapper = new MediaPayload();
        mediaWrapper.Item = items[i];

        Fragment fragment = new EhsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("InterActivityPayload", payload);
        bundle.putSerializable("MediaWrapper", mediaWrapper);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return items[position].Name;
    }

}
```

The fragment is 500+ lines, so I [dropboxed it](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4038856/ehsFragment.java). I can post it inline if people prefer, but it's a lot of code.

Comment: Can you post the code for your `ViewPager`'s adapter and the code from the `Fragment`?

Comment: It may be running out of memory when you are creating the different Bitmaps (e.g. `BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), ralImages.get(ralIndex));` or wherever else Bitmaps are created. Check LogCat and see if it has any messages that might indicate that.  Here is a good article on [Loading large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Does your fragment's layout really need to be rebuilt? Looking at the `LoadTiles` method you seem to be building the layout each time. Wouldn't make more sense to have all the views already in the inflated layout and then simply implement the logic to get/set the image with some sort of cache?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'd prefer not to build the view each time. I'll see if I can build a layout that already contains the custom child layouts.